# How can I use custom themes in nativescript?

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am currently working on an application which may have a different theme depending on the client, previously this functionality was made with [akylas-teme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-akylas-themes).

but I migrated the project to angular 11 and nativescript 7 so this solution no longer works for me.

How could I carry out the same functionality that I had previously? With dynamic themes for each client.

I will provide more information about my project if it is necessary to carry out the solution, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

add a root class to your page/s

xml/html:

```
<Page class="blue-theme">...
```

js:

```
changeTheme () {
    page.className = 'red-theme';
}
```

scss:

```
@import "~@nativescript/theme/core";
@import "~@nativescript/theme/default";
.blue-theme {
    @import "~@nativescript/theme/blue";
}
```